# Grouped gap filling in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have some grouped time-series data, with gaps. I need to fill those gaps with nulls, would be very simple without groups in this data (look for example below). I know I can do that by left joining to Calendar table, but can't figure out how exactly.

Example of my raw data:
date - can be day, week, month, whatever, doesn't really matter here

```
date   | group   | data      |
-------+---------+-----------+
1      | a       | some_data |     
3      | a       | some_data |     
5      | b       | some_data |     
7      | b       | some_data |     
8      | b       | some_data |     
2      | c       | some_data |     
6      | c       | some_data |
```

Desired result:

```
date   | group   | data      |
-------+---------+-----------+
1      | a       | some_data |    
2      | a       |   null    |      
3      | a       | some_data |     
5      | b       | some_data |
6      | b       |   null    |          
7      | b       | some_data |     
8      | b       | some_data |     
2      | c       | some_data |
3      | c       |   null    |     
4      | c       |   null    |     
5      | c       |   null    |          
6      | c       | some_data |
```

P.S. i know that it is very easy done with python or whatever, but i really need this to be done with SQL only

Comment: Before you start, learn what RDBMS you are really using. Don't just spam the tags with 4 completely different RBDMS... Then, once we know what your RDBMS *really* is, we can show you how to achieve what you're after.

Comment: I meant that I don't really care about specific RDBMS, I just want to know how to do this with raw SQL. Sorry if it is inappropriate, won't do that again. Thank you for your comment

Comment: Every RDBMS uses a different dialect of SQL; SQL on it's own isn't a language as there are so many different versions. When asking a SQL question it's therefore very important we know what RDBMS you are using so we can supply an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a `RECURSIVE CTE` that returns all the possible `date`s for each `group` and then a `LEFT` join to the table:

```
with cte as (
  select min(date) date, max(date) maxdate, `group`
  from tablename
  group by `group`
  union all
  select c.date + 1, maxdate, c.`group`
  from cte c
  where c.date < c.maxdate
)  
select c.date, c.`group`, t.data 
from cte c left join tablename t
on t.date = c.date and t.`group` = c.`group`
order by c.`group`, c.date
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=31764c6677d35f4e444a14e9fed475dd).
Results:

```
> date | group | data     
> ---: | :---- | :--------
>    1 | a     | some_data
>    2 | a     | null     
>    3 | a     | some_data
>    5 | b     | some_data
>    6 | b     | null     
>    7 | b     | some_data
>    8 | b     | some_data
>    2 | c     | some_data
>    3 | c     | null     
>    4 | c     | null     
>    5 | c     | null     
>    6 | c     | some_data
```